# How to filter an array which is inside an object which has other details as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I have an object

```
const object = {
 name:'XYZ',
 Others: 'XYZ',
 numbers:[2,3,4,5,6,5]
}
```

I want to filter numbers array which is inside the object and return the object with filtered array like this in which array has numbers 5 only.

```
{
 name:'XYZ',
 Others: 'XYZ',
 numbers:[5,5]
}
```

If I use filter in JavaScript like this

```
object.numbers.filter()
```

It returns only numbers array not complete object with other details like name.
What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign `object.numbers` with `filter` return like:

```js
const object = {
 name:'XYZ',
 Others: 'XYZ',
 numbers:[2,3,4,5,6,5]
};
object.numbers = object.numbers.filter(el => el === 5);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it works, what if I am setting state like this
this.setState({
            object:this.state.object.numbers.filter(n=> {
                return n == 5})
        })
Bcz I am not able to set object.numbers

Answer (score 1):

to make it work with `this.setState` you have to create a new Object:

```js
let object = {
 name:'XYZ',
 Others: 'XYZ',
 numbers:[2,3,4,5,6,5]
}

let updatedObject = {...object,numbers:object.numbers.filter(e => e === 5)}
console.log(updatedObject)
// this.setState(updateObject)
```